# PySpark Pivoting

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pivot

I want to use PySpark to pivot data from a number of tables but i need to do it in a strange way. Please see below for an example.

Original table:

```
Vehicle_id | Owner_ID    | Vehicle_Buy_Date
--------------------------------------------
1          | 1           | 01/01/2015
1          | 2           | 01/10/2014
2          | 1           | 10/10/2016
```

End result:

```
Vehicle_id | Owner_1_Buy_Date | Owner_2_Buy_Date
------------------------------------------------
1          |01/01/2015        |01/10/2014
2          |10/10/2016        |NULL
```

I understand that this is an unusual question to ask, as this isn't mostly done on database tables.

Is there any way of doing this type of pivoting in PySpark?

Answer (score 1):

The function in pyspark is called `pivot`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df.groupBy("Vehicle_id").pivot("Owner_ID").agg(psf.max("Vehicle_Buy_Date")).show()

    +----------+----------+----------+
    |Vehicle_id|         1|         2|
    +----------+----------+----------+
    |         1|01/01/2015|01/10/2014|
    |         2|10/10/2016|      null|
    +----------+----------+----------+
```

If you know the number of distinct `Owner_ID` you can specify it as a list argument in the `pivot` function, otherwise it will compute it itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code to get the required result:

```
NewDf = df.withColumn('id', F.concat(F.lit('Owner_'), F.col('owner_id'), F.lit('_Buy_Date')).groupBy('Vehicle_id').pivot('id').agg(F.first('Vehicle_Buy_Date'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to transpose your data, it's easy to `reduce` your data to a structure like this (I this it's a better way) :

```
Vehicle_id | Owner_ID_Vehicle_Buy_Date_Reduce
--------------------------------------------
1          | [{"Owner_ID":1, Vehicle_Buy_Date: 01/01/2015},{ "Owner_ID": 2,   Vehicle_Buy_Date: 01/10/2014}]
2          | [{"Owner_ID":1, Vehicle_Buy_Date: 10/10/2016}]
```

How do yoy want transpose a structure like this ?

```
Vehicle_id | Owner_ID    | Vehicle_Buy_Date
--------------------------------------------
1          | 1           | 01/01/2015
1          | 2           | 01/10/2014
1          | 3           | 01/10/2013
2          | 4           | 10/10/2016
...        | ...         | ...
9          | 123         | 10/10/2017
```