# Juxtapose two PySpark df columns using information from two other columns

Tags: python, datatable, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have four columns in my PySpark dataframe:

```
'drivers','cars','topSpeeds','dates'
```

Suppose each driver has achieved different top speeds with different cars at different dates, and different cars have achieved different top speeds with different drivers at different dates.

I can take the average of top speeds for a driver for each car over all dates as follows:

```
df.groupBy("drivers").mean()
```

I think this works without specifying that I'm averaging by topSpeed because topSpeed is the only column with numerical values.

Similarly, I can get the average of top speeds for a car with each driver over all dates:

```
df.groupBy("cars").mean()
```

Now, I want to compare the averages of each driver with each car over each date, so I want a table where the drivers are the columns and the cars are the rows, and each table entry is the average of that driver with that specific car.

Can you think of a way to make this table in PySpark?

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004009/pyspark-pivoting) should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_gb = df.groupBy('drivers', 'cars').agg(F.mean('topSpeeds').alias('avg_topSpeeds'))

df_out = df_gb.groupBy('cars').pivot('drivers').agg(F.max('avg_topSpeeds'))
```